# A particular exercise on convergence of recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am given a sequence defined by 
$$
x_1=2 \ \text{and} \ x_{n+1}=x_n + \dfrac{1}{x_n} \ \text{for} \ n=1,2,\dots
$$
I want to show that it is strictly increasing and that $x_n \to +\infty$.

*Attempt at a solution*:

That it is strictly increasing, I sense I need to use induction. Namely, I want to show that for all $n$, $x_n <x_{n+1}$. This statement is true for $n=1$ and I assume it is true for $n=k$ and I need to show that this implies it is true for $k+1$. Having hit a brickwall with this attempt I need some guidance.

As far as $x_n\to +\infty$ is concerned,I need to show that it is not bounded. For if it is increasing and not bounded this would imply it diverges to infinity. Therefore I have to show that for all $M>0$ there exists a $\tilde{n}=\tilde{n}(M)$ such that $x_{\tilde{n}}>M$.

Is my understanding correct? Any hints on the proof would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_{n+1}=x_n + \dfrac{1}{x_n}$ implies $x^2_{n+1}=x^2_n +2+ \dfrac{1}{x^2_n}>x^2_n +2$, so we can easily prove $x^2_n\ge2n+2$ by induction: it is true for $n=1$, because $x^2_1=4=2\cdot1+2$. If we know that it's true for $n$, i.e. $x^2_n\ge2n+2$, then $x^2_{n+1}>x^2_n+2\ge2n+2+2=2(n+1)+2$ (induction step).
 This means $x_n\ge\sqrt{2n+2}$, since $x_n>0$ (by induction, too). The inequality is strict, except for $n=1$, naturally.

Comment: The last inequality $x_n \geq \sqrt{2n}$ should be strict, right?

Comment: @EEEB That was a typo, I've corrected it.

Comment: How did you get $x_n^2 \geq 2n+2$? from the previous givens? I mean what was the thought process that lead you there?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is increasing. If it is bounded, it has a finite limit $\ell$. What can be the value of this $\ell$?